# Pinning parallel process using UNix system calls

Tags: unix, process, parallel-processing, fork, pinning

```
for i in `seq 1 8` ; do
    (./runProgram &)
done
```

Dear Fellows,
I know how to create parallel processes by creating 8 independent processes, the next thing I am in search for is how to

i-Run 8 copies concurrently with processor pinning (each copy on is own processor core)

ii-Run 16 copies concurrently with processor pinning (2 copies per core)

iii-Run 8 copies concurrently with processor pinning as per “iii” and flipping processor core to the furthest core after a particular function call in the code.

Current configuration of my cpu is 8 cores.it is running Fedora OS. I dont know the process ids in advance.

please suggest.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For CPU affinity, try `taskset`: [How can I set the processor affinity of a process on Linux?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/73/376)

Comment: I dont know the process ids in advance.

Comment: You can use `taskset` to launch a new process, you don't need to know its ID in advance. Just use `$i` to compute the CPU number, e.g. subtract 1 for case **i**: `taskset -c $((i-1)) ./runProgram &`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve i and ii is to use the `taskset` command:

Case i:

```
for i in `seq 0 7`; do
  taskset -c $i ./runProgram &
done
```

Case ii:

```
for i in `seq 0 7`; do
  taskset -c $i ./runProgram &
  taskset -c $i ./runProgram &
done
```

Case iii: See the manual pages for `sched_getaffinity(2)` and `sched_setaffinity(2)` on how to change the pinning in code.